# How to calculate the variant allelic fraction (VAF) from VEP output?

Tags: python, biopython, vep

*This question was also asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9565421/)*

How can I calculate the variant allelic fraction from the VEP file for multiple human samples?

I used the ensembl-vep and it is human data.

Comment: Please show a) your VEP output and b) describe what variant allelic fraction  means. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you just have a VEP output (i.e. VCF) without raw genotypes then you cannot calculate the allelic fraction.

Comment: thanks user438383, how can calculate it if i have the vcf file?

Comment: @Joman See: https://www.biostars.org/p/147443/